# Class and Object, add old value with new value through input and transfer value to another object ~

Tags: java

Write a tariff set method to switch to a different tariff.

```
public String getTransfer() {
    return transfer;
}

public void setTransfer(String transfer) {
    this.htarif = transfer;
}
```

how to transfer tariff from one to another and how can i print out inside main ?

Next: Write a "top up" method that allows you to increase the credit by a specified amount. Make sure that the credit can only be increased, but not reduced.

```
public Guthaben() { }

public Guthaben(int credit) {
    this.credit = credit;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int icredit;

    Topup currentcredit = new Topup();

    System.out.println("Amount Credit you want to top up: ");
    icredit = input.nextInt();
    currentcredit.addCredit(icredit);
    System.out.println("Credit: " + currentcredit.getCurrentCredit());
}

public void addCredit(int credit) {
    this.credit = credit + credit;
}

public void newCredit(int newCredit) {
    this.credit += newCredit;
    increaseCredit++;
}
```

**Now the problem**:
I want to increase the credit with input. And make input add the amount with the old credit. 
What is missing?

Comment: In your add credit method you should probably check if the parameter passed is greater than 0 if you don’t want it reduced.

Comment: do you mean `public void addCredit(int credit) {
    this.credit = this.credit + credit;
}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, change the add credit method to be like that. it may work as expected

```
public void addCredit(int credit){
    if(credit > 0) 
        this.credit += credit;
}
```